# jQuery validation trigger error message

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, validation

I have a kinda wierd problem. I want to trigger a jquery-valdation errormessage on an element even thou it's valid.

Scenario:
I have a large form. One of the inputs is for PersonalId. It's optional to enter that PersonalId. 
Beside that input i have a normal button (not the submit-button). If you click on that (fetching information from ajax) and the PersonalId field is empty i want to trigger that Error-message.

Is that possible with jQuery Validate or do i need to create my own function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manually set unobtrusive validation error on a textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380278/manually-set-unobtrusive-validation-error-on-a-textbox)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

> Is that possible with jQuery Validate or do i need to create my own function?

Both, sort of. You can use the `showErrors` function to display errors on the form manually, but since you don't want this to be a rule that is enabled when you *submit* the form, you'll have to do your own checking for the value in the input.

Something like:

```
var $validator = $("#myform").validate();
$("#checkid").click(function() {
    var errors;

    if (!$("#personalid").val()) {
        /* Build up errors object, name of input and error message: */
        errors = { personalid: "Please enter an ID to check" };
        /* Show errors on the form */
        $validator.showErrors(errors);            
    }        
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/XjZer/

Note that the form will still submit if there is nothing in the `personalid` field.

Comment: I have same problem but how can I trigger error for multidimentional name. I could not solve this by your solution. e.g. 
`field = "email"; var element = "data[User]["+field+"]"; errors = { element : field_error }; $validator.showErrors(errors);`

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function