# Jquery Validation ShowErrors method shows error in a Label instead of Span

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

My question is somewhat related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789702/manually-adding-removing-validation-errors-to-jquery-validator/12828952)

Here is a [JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ughCm/255/)  to see what is happening I am using jquery validation version 1.14.0.

```
<Form id="myform">
        <div class="editor-label">
          <label for="FirstName">First name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
          <input class="text-box single-line" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="">
          <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="FirstName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
 </Form>

 var form= $("#myForm");
  var validator=$("#myform").validate();
  validator.showErrors({
        "FirstName": "test error"
    });
```

Also validator.valid() returns true if I use validator.showErrors to make the input invalid.How can I make validator.showErrors make the form invalid in addition to showing the errors?

Comment: You don't "make" the form invalid.  It's valid/invalid based on if the field's values pass/fail the validation rules you've set.  Otherwise, there is no point in the validation plugin whatsoever.

Comment: The showerrors is a manual way of making a field invalid and it does not use any rule. Thats why the validator.valid() returns true if the field is invalidated using showerrors methos.

Comment: **You are absolutely incorrect!**  [Try reading the documentation:](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#showerrors) *"showErrors:  A custom message display handler. Gets the map of errors as the first argument and an array of errors as the second"* ~ In other words, a custom way to display the ***existing*** error messages generated by the validation rules already in place.  I have no idea why you think manually generating messages is any part of this.  There is absolutely no point in having a validation plugin if you're just going to manually add/remove messages.

Comment: I meant custom way of making the fields invalid not manual sorry for the confusion. But my issue is why does validator.valid() return true if I use Showerrors to invalidate the controls but return false if some fields are required and not filled?

Comment: You're still not making any sense.  You cannot "make" the fields "invalid".  Just because you force a bit of text in place of the error message does not make it "invalid".  They are only invalid if the data entered into them fails the defined validation rule(s).   That's the whole point of the plugin!

Comment: Yeah so that's what my question is. How to make showerrors make the fields invalid in addition to showing the errors and why does it show it in a label instead of a span which is the default. See my jsFiddle for more details

Comment: You can not programmatically "make" the field "invalid".  It's valid or invalid based solely on how the value of the field compares to your validation rules.  Period.  If you simply want to programmatically place/remove messages, then you would not need a validation plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own logic to show errors in `<span>` instated of `label`

Please see here for full example. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ughCm/256/)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you cant set your custom messages using the `invalidHandler`

from docs:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
    // 'this' refers to the form
    var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
    if (errors) {
      var message = errors == 1
        ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted'
        : 'You missed ' + errors + ' fields. They have been highlighted';
      $("div.error span").html(message);
      $("div.error").show();
    } else {
      $("div.error").hide();
    }
  }
});
```

[Link to Docs](https://jqueryvalidation.org/category/plugin/#invalidhandler)

Comment: There is an attribute called `errorList ` inside `validator`, there you can get which inputs has errors.

Answer (score 0):

> *Also `validator.valid()` returns `true` if I use `validator.showErrors` to make the input invalid.*

### You cannot programmatically "make" the field or form "invalid" by inserting a piece of text into the page.

**Valid/Invalid status is based solely on how the entered value of a field compares to the declared validation rules.**  That's why `.valid()` is not working as you expected; it's correctly determining validity based on your validation rules, not whether an arbitrary message exists.

> *How can I make `validator.showErrors` make the form invalid in addition to showing the errors?*

### You cannot!  You seem to be confusing a manually generated piece of text with actual data validation.  The form and/or field will only be "invalid" when the entered data does not follow your validation rules.

If you simply want to programmatically toggle text messages based on your own private criteria, then you would not need a validation plugin.

On the other hand, why not [create a custom validation rule](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/) for whatever you're trying to do, and let the plugin properly handle the validation messages.

Comment: I needed a validation plugin because I use other features of it like the required, Regex...etc. I use the showerros as extra custom things to invalidate my fields in addition to the build in rules i specified. so You can't tell me I don't need the plugin.

Comment: @AmeteBlessed, don't take one line out of context when the very next line gives you a viable workaround.