# ASP.NET MVC Manually remove unobtrusive validation error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

With regard to the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380278/manually-set-unobtrusive-validation-error-on-a-textbox/7988611), how does one remove these errors once they've been shown and resolved?

I've added an error via:

```
var errorArray = {};
errorArray["Slug"] = 'Some error message for the Slug text box';
$('#SomeFormId').validate().showErrors(errorArray);
```

But I can't get the errors to clear after an ajax post of the form.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var validator = form.validate();
$('#SomeFormId').find('.field-validation-error span').each(function () {
    validator.settings.success($(this));
});
validator.resetForm();
```