# Make field not required based to dropdown list selection MVC 5

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC 5 app, I have a form with a dropdown and some fields which are required. I need to change this attribute of the fields when the dropdown selection is change.

I have this enum

```
public enum OrderKind
{

    Market,
    Research,

}
```

from which I fill the dropdown list. I have use javascript so to show or hide fields which work.

Something as

```
 $(function () {

  $('#orderkind').change(function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            if (value == "Market") {
                $(datefrom).hide();
                $(datefrom).hide();
                $("#fromDate").attr("required", false);
                $("#toDate").attr("required", false);
    else if (value == "Research") {
                $(datefrom).show();
                $(datefrom).show();
                $("#fromDate").attr("required", true);
                $("#toDate").attr("required", true);
                fromDate.setCustomValidity('Please Fill the date from field');
                toDate.setCustomValidity('Please Fill the date to field');
          }
```

but it makes the date fields always required, even when they are filled it displays the message. 
Is there a way to check the dropdown list value from Controller?
thank you!

Comment: First fix syntax errors and then use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

Comment: Consider a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIf]` or similar conditional validation attribute so you get both client and server side validation out of the box

Comment: Satpal, thank you for your reply, I used your suggestion but nothing change. It always display the message.

Comment: what in the value variable before if condition?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, hello I tried foolproof but when I submit the form I get the error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' Any idea?

Comment: Then you did not use it correctly :). If you have a property (say) `public OrderKind Kind { get; set; }` and you use `[RequiredIf("Kind", "Market")]` applied to another property, then if you select 'Market', that other property will display an error message if left blank (but your will not get an error is 'Research' is selected)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Now I dont get the error but it doesn't displays the message and it doesn't save the record when I select `Market`

Comment: Did you include the relevant scripts? Did you include `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` to display the message? Either ask a new question with the relevant code or edit this one (we cannot guess what you have done wrong)

Comment: ok I post a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39509051/make-field-not-required-based-to-dropdown-list-selection-foolproof-mvc-5

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change your enum to

```
public enum OrderKind
{
    Market = 1,
    Research = 2,
}
```

Then, bind the value into your drop down list and `add external (default)` value to it.

Answer (score 0):

give an id to your form like below

```
using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formID" }))
   { }
```

in Jquery

```
$("#formID").submit(function(e){
//your checking
//you can prevent form submission here like
e.preventdefault()
//and you can show validation error for dropdown list or show as alert
});
```

you can set validation error in Jquery like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380278/manually-set-unobtrusive-validation-error-on-a-textbox)

Comment: thank you for your reply. I add your code but my checks doesn't work. I mean I have to display and hide some of my fields based on dropdown list.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code, Hope this helps

```
$(function () {
```

`$('#orderkind').change(function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            if (value == "Market") {
                $(datefrom).hide();
                $(datefrom).hide();
                $("#fromDate").removeAttr('required');
                $("#toDate").removeAttr('required');
    else if (value == "Research") {
                $(datefrom).show();
                $(datefrom).show();
                $("#fromDate").attr('required', 'required');
                $("#toDate").attr('required', 'required');
                fromDate.setCustomValidity('Please Fill the date from field');
                toDate.setCustomValidity('Please Fill the date to field');
          }
 });`

Comment: Where is the difference on my code? The brackets?  I already have them. I just didn't do a good paste. Thank you

Comment: $("#fromDate").removeAttr('required'); here change.

Comment: it doesn't work, it always ask for the dates. Thank you