# Jquery Unobstrusive validation show errors manually for Valid

Tags: jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have added errors manually to my input using the link in here  [Here](https://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.showErrors/) and the example in  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380278/manually-set-unobtrusive-validation-error-on-a-textbox) but when I try  `$("#myshowErrors").valid()` after I added the errors it becomes true?

here is my code

```
var validator = $( "#myshowErrors" ).validate();
validator.showErrors({
  "firstname": "I know that your firstname is Pete, Pete!"
});
```

I am not able to make the client validation fail.  How can I make `form.valid()` to return `false`?

I don't want to make `form.valid()=false;` manually I want that to be taken care of by just setting the errors.

Comment: You'll need to do a better job showing us the code.

Comment: Click on the links in my question to see the code.

Comment: You are not supposed to use external links instead of showing your own code.  Please click on this link:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Agree. I just added code.

Comment: Where is the rest of the relevant code?  Nobody can help you if you don't care enough to write a good question.  Where is the `#myshowErrors` element?  Where is the rest of the relevant rendered markup?

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely unclear by the lack of code in your question, but I think you might misunderstand where to attach [the `.valid()` method](https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/).

This method only gets attached to a selector representing a *single* `<form>` element...

```
$('#myform').valid();  // triggers validation on the entire form
```

Or to any selector that represents a *single* form input element...

```
$('#myform input[name="myinput"]').valid();  // triggers validation on one input element
```

When `.valid()` is called, validation is triggered on the selected element, error message(s) is/are displayed, and the method will return `true` or `false`.

The `.valid()` method can never be attached to a selector that represents more than one element, or a collection of elements without also using a jQuery `.each()`.

---

**EDITS:**

`showErrors` is just for showing *existing* errors.  You cannot "invalidate" a field by calling `showErrors`.  Fields are either valid or invalid based solely on what is contained within that field.

---

You've tagged the question with Unobtrusive Validation. Since jQuery Validation is handled automatically via the Unobtrusive Validation plugin, you are not allowed to call your own instance of the `.validate()` method. That's because the Unobtrusive plugin automatically constructs and calls `.validate()`. Once it's called, the plugin is initialized, it cannot be called again, and all subsequent calls are always ignored.

Comment: So my question is if I invalidate an input my self using validator.showErrors({
  "firstname": "I know that your firstname is Pete, Pete!"
}); why would $('#myform').valid() return true. I want it to return to false if I invalidate  any one inout from my form.

Comment: @AmeteBlessed, because you made a mistake someplace.  I cannot help you since I cannot see your code.

Comment: @AmeteBlessed, I also have no idea why you think you can "invalidate" a field by calling `showErrors`.  Fields are either valid or invalid based solely on what is contained within that field.

Comment: So what would be the best way to invalidate a field on the fly?

Comment: @AmeteBlessed, that is not possible.  Fields are valid/invalid based solely on what the user puts inside and I have no idea why you'd need to do such a thing.  Now if you want to change rules on the fly, that's another story.